# Windows Batch File: Look for directory, if not exist, create, then move file to it

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file, or other script, to take the contents of one folder to a folder containing its name in another directory.  For example:

ShowName.Episode.Title.mkv should be moved to \movies\showname.  if \movies\showname\ doesn't exist, the script would create it.

There are, on average, 10-15 files at a time that would need moved.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "tokens=1-4delims=." %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.*.*.mkv" '
 ) DO (
  MD "%destdir%\%%a" 2>NUL
  MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d" "%destdir%\%%a\"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

This should do your moves. You'd have to change the directory names, of course - no idea where your source directory is, but destination becomes `\movies` in your case.

May be an idea to try `ECHO MOVE` first, just to make sure that the move is as-required.

The `2>nul` on the `MD` suppresses the error messages saying the directory already exists.

Adding `>nul` to the end of the `MOVE` line will suppress the `file moved` message.

Comment: easy answer to a simple problem.

Answer (score 10):

You can conditionally create the folder with:

```
if not exist \movies\showname mkdir \movies\showname
```

To move a file into it:

```
move ShowName.Episode.Title.mkv \movies\showname
```

To get more information about these commands, open a command prompt and type:

```
help if
```

and

```
help move
```