# Checking if directory exists using batch file

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line

I am trying to use the [answer posted in another Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1466528/4832435)

According to that post, I should be able to use the following batch script to test if a link is a directory

```
if exist %1\* echo Directory
```

However, I am not sure how I am supposed to use this.

I have tried replacing

```
if exist %1\* echo Directory
```

with

```
SET "t=%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\testDir"
if exist %t\* echo Directory
```

But this doesn't echo out Directory like it should (testDir directory exists on my desktop)

Does the %1 in this conext represent something?

Comment: It has been ages since I last wrote a DOS/Windows shell script (it's MS shell thing, right?), so I can't remember many things. %1 is the first parameter of your script, e.g. if you run `myscript.bat testDir`, then %1 will be "testDir”. I suspect your `SET` line; for debugging purposes, I would include an `echo %t` line there to check if the variable's value is OK.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a folder exists using a .bat file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 1):

I generally use:

```
if exist %1\. echo Directory
```

EDIT: Assuming %1 is a directory, the . is a 'file' that is always there, so it's presence ensures it is a directory and not a file.

Comment: why dont you explain why you use **%1\.** instead of **%1\*** and how to use it, your answer doesnt let much off...

Comment: I can't remember how this behave in MS-DOS, but in Windows' `cmd.exe`, this also returns true for files…

Comment: @donttellthem as I remember aschipfl is correct, %1 will show exists on files and the "\." ensures that only directories match. The example shows pretty well how it works, where it echoes "directory" only on directories.

Answer (score 0):

`%1` is the first command line parameter.

```
C:\Users\User>if exist c:\windows echo windows exist
windows exist

C:\Users\User>if exist c:\windows1 echo windows exist

C:\Users\User>
```

And a list of some punctuation

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```

And if you want to know if a directory or file.

```
@Echo off
pushd %1 >nul 2>&1  
If errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is a folder
If errorlevel 1 Echo %~nx1 is not a folder
Popd

If /i "%cmdcmdline:~0,6%"=="cmd /c" pause
```