# What is the difference between %1 and %1\NUL when checking for folder existance in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I found a batch script example that checks whether a folder (given as argument) exists with the following fragment:

```
if not exist %1\NUL goto errorDir

rem throw error if folder doesn't exist.
:errorDir
echo ERROR Input directory doesn't exist... exiting.
goto :end
```

This works fine when called without quotes, e.g. `script.bat my\path\to\folder`. But it fails if I hand over a folder path within quotes, `script.bat "my\path\to\folder with spaces"` - even though the folder exists.

I then realized that apparently I do not need the `\NUL` part (from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44253084/6409572)) and it will work fine with quotes:

```
if not exist %1 goto errorDir
```

Now I am wondering: Is there an advantage for using `\NUL`? And how would I use it corretly so it works with quotes? Just wrapping it in quotes didn't work for me (`if not exist "%1\NUL"`).

Comment: Probably trying to differentiate between files and directories

Comment: There is no advantage in using `\nul`, but for me, the safest option is `\.` Your command will look like this: ```If Not Exist "%~1\." GoTo errorDir```.