# How to check if a sub-path exist using batch file

Tags: batch-file, create-directory

I would like to be able to get path from user like (C:\Users\mehak\Downloads\folderA\folderB)

```
SET /P USER_INSTALL= Installation Path :
```

Now i want to check if (FolderA) exists then create a subfolder (folderB).

Does anybody have any idea how can i create a batch file to allow me to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking if a folder exists using a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033801/checking-if-a-folder-exists-using-a-bat-file)

Answer (score 0):

```
MD "%user_install%\folderb"  >nul 2>nul
if exist "%user_install%\folderb\." (
 echo Folderb created
) else (
 echo Folderb not created
)
```

Will create folderb under `%user_install%` whether or not *either* already exists.

Don't move the parentheses in the `if` statement - they are quite critical.